# Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

What I'm wondering is if `lock xchg` will have similar behavior to `mfence` from the perspective of one thread accessing a memory location that is being mutated (lets just say at random) by other threads. Does it guarantee I get the most up to date value? Of memory read/write instructions that follow after?

The reason for my confusion is:

> 8.2.2 “Reads or writes cannot be reordered with I/O instructions, locked instructions, or serializing instructions.”
>
> **-Intel 64 Developers Manual Vol. 3**

Does this apply across threads?

`mfence` states:

> Performs a serializing operation on all load-from-memory and store-to-memory instructions that were issued prior the MFENCE instruction. This serializing operation guarantees that every load and store instruction that precedes in program order the MFENCE instruction is globally visible before any load or store instruction that follows the MFENCE instruction is globally visible. The MFENCE instruction is ordered with respect to all load and store instructions, other MFENCE instructions, any SFENCE and LFENCE instructions, and any serializing instructions (such as the CPUID instruction).
>
> **-Intel 64 Developers Manual Vol 3A**

This *sounds* like a stronger guarantee. As it sounds like `mfence` is almost flushing the write buffer, or at least reaching out to the write buffer and other cores to ensure my future load/stores are up to date.

When bench-marked both instructions take on the order of ~100 cycles to complete. So I can't see that big of a difference either way.

Primarily I am just confused. I instructions based around `lock` used in mutexes, but then these contain no memory fences. Then I see *lock free* programming that uses memory fences, but no locks. I understand AMD64 has a very strong memory model, but stale values can persist in cache. If `lock` doesn't behave the same behavior as `mfence` then how do mutexes help you see the most recent value?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027590/do-we-need-mfence-when-using-xchg

Comment: xchg includes the lock logic, so lock / xchg is redundant.

Comment: I'm aware, except clang actually emits lock xchg for atomic swapping size_t with Sequential ordering on x86_64. I was kind of copying and pasting.

Comment: @hidefromkgb this states that instructions cannot be re-order but it does not answer if load/stores are serialized like what happens with `mfense`.

Comment: Locked atomic read-modify-write on x86 are sequentially consistent. AFAIR, `lock add [mem], 0` or `lock or [mem], 0` or `lock and [mem], -1` have been used in place of `mfence` on microarchitectures where `mfence` is particularly slow. The trick is finding a memory location that is guaranteed to be accessible, in cache, but not in use. I seem to remember a decent offset from the stack pointer being used for `[mem]`.

Comment: `mfence` sounds to me like serializing ALL memory reads/writes. `xchg` can focus on the memory in argument only? (letting CPU execute other memory writes/reads in different order). Then again the x86 memory model is too strong for that one to happen? I'm more like asking, have the x86 memory model articles open in other tabs for weeks, keeping them for later when I will be in mood to study it thoroughly.

Comment: Note that "lock free" doesn't mean that code doesn't use LOCK prefixes. It means code that can never, even in theory, have all threads blocked. In other words the code can never completely "lock up".

Comment: They're both full memory barriers.  Don't have time to write a full answer, but see some of the memory-ordering links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  MFENCE may also imply some other semantics about partially serializing the instruction stream, not just memory, at least on AMD CPUs where it's lower throughput than `lock add` for use as a memory barrier.

Comment: If you can write a full answer I'll happily accept it. I'm just looking for concrete sources.

Comment: Update: I wasn't considering NT stores in my last comment.  For memory-ordering in lock-free algorithms, `mov [shared], eax` / `mfence` is compatible with `xchg [shared], eax` as a way to implement `shared.store(eax, std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.  But as BeeOnRope's answer points out, `mfence` having lower back-to-back throughput suggests that it's doing something different, and maybe `lock`ed ops aren't fencing NT stores.

Comment: @EOF "_Locked atomic read-modify-write on x86 are sequentially consistent_" Yes, but "sequentially consistent" is about a set of operations not a specific operation. You have to say what are all the operations considered.

Comment: @curiousguy Maybe you would accept "Locked atomic read-modify-write on x86 include a full memory barrier"?

Comment: @EOF Yep: "full memory barrier" is an assertion about the current execution. It's fully defined in that context (the CPU).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe your question is the same as asking if `mfence` has the same barrier semantics as the `lock`-prefixed instructions on x86, or if it provides fewer<sup>1</sup> or additional guarantees in some cases.

My current best answer is that it was Intel's *intent* and that the ISA documentation guarantees that `mfence` and `lock`ed instructions provide the same fencing semantics, but that due to implementation oversights, `mfence` actually provides stronger fencing semantics on recent hardware (since at least Haswell). In particular, `mfence` can fence a subsequent *non-temporal load* from a WC-type memory region, while `lock`ed instructions do not.

We know this because Intel tells us this in processor errata such as [HSD162 (Haswell)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-specification-update.pdf) and [SKL155 (Skylake)](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.pdf) which tell us that locked instructions don't fence a subsequent non-temporal read from WC-memory:

> **MOVNTDQA From WC Memory May Pass Earlier Locked Instructions**
>
> **Problem:** An execution of (V)MOVNTDQA (streaming load instruction) that loads from WC (write  combining) memory may appear to pass an
>   earlier locked instruction that accesses a  different cache line.
>
> **Implication:** Software that expects a lock to fence subsequent (V)MOVNTDQA instructions may not  operate properly.
>
> **Workaround:** None  identified.  Software  that  relies  on  a  locked  instruction  to  fence  subsequent executions of (V)MOVNTDQA
>   should insert  an MFENCE instruction between the locked instruction
>   and subsequent (V)MOVNTDQA instruction.

From this, we can determine that (1) Intel probably *intended* that locked instructions fence NT loads from WC-type memory, or else this wouldn't be an errata<sup>0.5</sup> and (2) that locked instructions *don't* actually do that, and Intel wasn't able to or chose not to fix this with a microcode update, and `mfence` is recommended instead.

In Skylake, `mfence` actually lost its additional fencing capability with respect to NT loads, as per **SKL079: MOVNTDQA From WC Memory May Pass Earlier MFENCE Instructions** - this has pretty much the same text as the `lock`-instruction errata, but applies to `mfence`. However, the status of this errata is "It is possible for the BIOS to contain a workaround for this erratum.", which is generally Intel-speak for "a microcode update addresses this".

This sequence of errata can perhaps be explained by timing: the Haswell errata only appears in early 2016, years after the the release of that processor, so we can assume the issue came to Intel's attention some moderate amount of time before that. At this point Skylake was almost certainly already out in the wild, with apparently a less conservative `mfence` implementation which also didn't fence NT loads on WC-type memory regions. Fixing the way locked instructions works all the way back to Haswell was probably either impossible or expensive based on their wide use, but some way was needed to fence NT loads. `mfence` apparently already did the job on Haswell, and Skylake would be fixed so that `mfence` worked there too.

It doesn't really explain why SKL079 (the `mfence` one) appeared in January 2016, nearly two years before SKL155 (the `locked` one) appeared in late 2017, or why the latter appeared so much after the identical Haswell errata, however.

One might speculate on what Intel will do in the future. Since they weren't able/willing to change the `lock` instruction for Haswell through Skylake, representing hundreds of million (billions?) of deployed chips, they'll never be able to guarantee that locked instructions fence NT loads, so they might consider making this the documented, architected behavior in the future. Or they might update the locked instructions, so they do fence such reads, but as a practical matter you can't rely on this probably for a decade or more, until chips with the current non-fencing behavior are almost out of circulation.

Similar to Haswell, according to [BV116](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/3rd-gen-core-desktop-specification-update.pdf) and [BJ138](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiL7Lzw9_PgAhUKvI8KHSIlA7AQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.intel.com%2Fcontent%2Fwww%2Fus%2Fen%2Fembedded%2Fproducts%2Fsugar-bay%2F2nd-gen-core-desktop-specification-update.html&usg=AOvVaw0hwqOlxrtBSBlVNpOmzQfb), NT loads may pass earlier locked instructions on Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge, respectively. It's possible that earlier microarchitectures also suffer from this issue. This "bug" does not seem to exist in Broadwell and microarchitectures after Skylake.

Peter Cordes has written a bit about the Skylake `mfence` change at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50496379/149138).

The remaining part of this answer is my original answer, before I knew about the errata, and which is left mostly for historical interest.

## Old Answer

My informed guess at the answer is that `mfence` provides additional barrier functionality: between accesses using weakly-ordered instructions (e.g., NT stores) and perhaps between accesses weakly-ordered *regions* (e.g., WC-type memory).

That said, this is just an informed guess and you'll find details of my investigation below.

## Details

### Documentation

It isn't exactly clear the extent that the memory consistency effects of `mfence` differs that provided by `lock`-prefixed instruction (including `xchg` with a memory operand, which is implicitly locked).

I think it is safe to say that solely with respect to write-back memory regions and not involving any non-temporal accesses, `mfence` provides the same ordering semantics as `lock`-prefixed operation.

What is open for debate is whether `mfence` differs at all from `lock`-prefixed instructions when it comes to scenarios outside the above, in particular when accesses involve regions other than WB regions or when non-temporal (streaming) operations are involved.

For example, you can find some suggestions (such as [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/298011#comment-1530531) or [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/278235#comment-1463005)) that `mfence` implies strong barrier semantics when WC-type operations (e.g., NT stores) are involved.

For example, quoting Dr. McCalpin in [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/545063#comment-1819775) (emphasis added):

> The fence instruction is only needed to be absolutely sure that all of
>   the non-temporal stores are visible before a subsequent "ordinary"
>   store.  The most obvious case where this matters is in a parallel
>   code, where the "barrier" at the end of a parallel region may include
>   an "ordinary" store.  Without a fence, the processor might still have
>   modified data in the Write-Combining buffers, but pass through the
>   barrier and allow other processors to read "stale" copies of the
>   write-combined data.  This scenario might also apply to a single
>   thread that is migrated by the OS from one core to another core (not
>   sure about this case).
>
> I can't remember the detailed reasoning (not enough coffee yet this
>   morning), but the instruction you want to use after the non-temporal
>   stores is an MFENCE.  **According to Section 8.2.5 of Volume 3 of the
>   SWDM, the MFENCE is the only fence instruction that prevents both
>   subsequent loads and subsequent stores from being executed ahead of
>   the completion of the fence.**   I am surprised that this is not
>   mentioned in Section 11.3.1, which tells you how important it is to
>   manually ensure coherence when using write-combining, but does not
>   tell you how to do it!

Let's check out the referenced section 8.2.5 of the Intel SDM:

> Strengthening or Weakening the Memory-Ordering Model
>
> The Intel 64 and
>   IA-32 architectures provide several mechanisms for strengthening or
>   weakening the memory- ordering model to handle special programming
>   situations. These mechanisms include:
>
> • The I/O instructions, locking
>   instructions, the LOCK prefix, and serializing instructions force
>   stronger ordering on the processor.
>
> • The SFENCE instruction
>   (introduced to the IA-32 architecture in the Pentium III processor)
>   and the LFENCE and MFENCE instructions (introduced in the Pentium 4
>   processor) provide memory-ordering and serialization capabilities for
>   specific types of memory operations.
>
> These mechanisms can be used as follows:
>
> Memory mapped devices and
>   other I/O devices on the bus are often sensitive to the order of
>   writes to their I/O buffers. I/O instructions can be used to (the IN
>   and OUT instructions) impose strong write ordering on such accesses as
>   follows. Prior to executing an I/O instruction, the processor waits
>   for all previous instructions in the program to complete and for all
>   buffered writes to drain to memory. Only instruction fetch and page
>   tables walks can pass I/O instructions. Execution of subsequent
>   instructions do not begin until the processor determines that the I/O
>   instruction has been completed.
>
> Synchronization mechanisms in multiple-processor systems may depend
>   upon a strong memory-ordering model. Here, a program can use a locking
>   instruction such as the XCHG instruction or the LOCK prefix to ensure
>   that a read-modify-write operation on memory is carried out
>   atomically. Locking operations typically operate like I/O operations
>   in that they wait for all previous instructions to complete and for
>   all buffered writes to drain to memory (see Section 8.1.2, “Bus
>   Locking”).
>
> Program synchronization can also be carried out with
>   serializing instructions (see Section 8.3). These instructions are
>   typically used at critical procedure or task boundaries to force
>   completion of all previous instructions before a jump to a new section
>   of code or a context switch occurs. Like the I/O and locking
>   instructions, the processor waits until all previous instructions have
>   been completed and all buffered writes have been drained to memory
>   before executing the serializing instruction.
>
> The SFENCE, LFENCE, and
>   MFENCE instructions **provide a performance-efficient way of ensuring
>   load and store memory ordering between routines that produce
>   weakly-ordered results and routines that consume that data**. The
>   functions of these instructions are as follows:
>
> • SFENCE — Serializes
>   all store (write) operations that occurred prior to the SFENCE
>   instruction in the program instruction stream, but does not affect
>   load operations.
>
> • LFENCE — Serializes all load (read) operations that
>   occurred prior to the LFENCE instruction in the program instruction
>   stream, but does not affect store operations.
>
> • MFENCE — Serializes
>   all store and load operations that occurred prior to the MFENCE
>   instruction in the program instruction stream.
>
> **Note that the SFENCE,
>   LFENCE, and MFENCE instructions provide a more efficient method of
>   controlling memory ordering than the CPUID instruction.**

Contrary to Dr. McCalpin's interpretation<sup>2</sup>, I see this section as somewhat ambiguous as to whether `mfence` does something extra. The three sections referring to IO, locked instructions and serializing instructions do imply that they provide a full barrier between memory operations before and after the operation. They don't make any exception for weakly ordered memory and in the case of the IO instructions, one would also assume they need to work in a consistent way with weakly ordered memory regions since such are often used for IO.

Then the section for the `FENCE` instructions, it *explicitly* mentions weak memory regions: "The SFENCE, LFENCE, and MFENCE instructions **provide a performance-efficient way of ensuring load and store memory ordering between routines that produce weakly-ordered results and routines that consume that data."

Do we read between the lines and take this to mean that these are the only instructions that accomplish this and that the previously mentioned techniques (including locked instructions) don't help for weak memory regions? We can find some support for this idea by noting that fence instructions were introduced<sup>3</sup> at the same time as weakly-ordered non-temporal store instructions, and by text like that found in **11.6.13 Cacheability Hint Instructions** dealing specifically with weakly ordered instructions:

> The degree to which a consumer of data knows that the data is weakly
>   ordered can vary for these cases. As a result, the SFENCE or MFENCE
>   instruction should be used to ensure ordering between routines that
>   produce weakly-ordered data and routines that consume the data. SFENCE
>   and MFENCE provide a performance-efficient way to ensure ordering by
>   guaranteeing that every store instruction that precedes SFENCE/MFENCE
>   in program order is globally visible before a store instruction that
>   follows the fence.

Again, here the fence instructions are specifically mentioned to be appropriate for fencing weakly ordered instructions.

We also find support for the idea that locked instruction might not provide a barrier between weakly ordered accesses from the last sentence already quoted above:

> Note that the SFENCE,
>   LFENCE, and MFENCE instructions provide a more efficient method of
>   controlling memory ordering than the CPUID instruction.

Here is basically implies that the `FENCE` instructions essentially replace a functionality previously offered by the serializing `cpuid` in terms of memory ordering. However, if `lock`-prefixed instructions provided the same barrier capability as `cpuid`, that would likely have been the previously suggested way, since these are in general much faster than `cpuid` which often takes 200 or more cycles. The implication being that there were scenarios (probably weakly ordered scenarios) that `lock`-prefixed instructions didn't handle, and where `cpuid` was being used, and where `mfence` is now suggested as a replacement, implying stronger barrier semantics than `lock`-prefixed instructions.

However, we could interpret some of the above in a different way: note that in the context of the fence instructions it is often mentioned that they are *performance-efficient way* to ensure ordering. So it could be that these instructions are not intended to provide additional barriers, but simply more efficient barriers for.

Indeed, `sfence` at a few cycles is much faster than serializing instructions like `cpuid` or `lock`-prefixed instructions which are generally 20 cycles or more. On the other hand `mfence` *isn't* generally faster than locked instructions<sup>4</sup>, at least on modern hardware. Still, it could have been faster when introduced, or on some future design, or perhaps it was *expected* to be faster but that didn't pan out.

So I can't make a certain assessment based on these sections of the manual: I think you can make a reasonable argument that it could be interpreted either way.

We can further look at documentation for various non-temporal store instructions in the Intel ISA guide. For example, in the documentation for the non-temporal store `movnti` you find the following quote:

> Because the WC protocol uses a weakly-ordered memory consistency
>   model, a fencing operation implemented with the SFENCE or MFENCE
>   instruction should be used in conjunction with MOVNTI instructions if
>   multiple processors might use different memory types to read/write the
>   destination memory locations.

The part about "if multiple processors might use different memory types to read/write the destination memory locations" is a bit confusing to me. I would expect this rather to say something like "to enforce ordering in the globally visible write order between instructions using weakly ordered hints" or something like that. Indeed, the actual *memory type* (e.g., as defined by the MTTR) probably doesn't even come into play here: the ordering issues can arise solely in WB-memory when using weakly ordered instructions.

### Performance

The `mfence` instruction is reported to take 33 cycles (back-to-back latency) on modern CPUs based on Agner fog's instruction timing, but a more complex locked instructon like `lock cmpxchg` is reported to take only 18 cycles.

If `mfence` provided barrier semantics no stronger than `lock cmpxchg`, the latter is doing strictly more work and there is no apparent reason for `mfence` to take significantly *longer*. Of course you could argue that `lock cmpxchg` is simply more important than `mfence` and hence gets more optimization. This argument is weakened by the fact that *all* of the locked instructions are considerably faster than `mfence`, even infrequently used ones. Also, you would imagine that if there were a single barrier implementation shared by all the `lock` instructions, `mfence` would simply use the same one as that's the simplest and easiest to validation.

So the slower performance of `mfence` is, in my opinion, significant evidence that `mfence` is doing some *extra*.

---

<sup>0.5</sup> This isn't a water-tight argument. Some things may appear in errata that are apparently "by design" and not a bug, such as `popcnt` false dependency on destination register - so some errata can be considered a form of documentation to update expectations rather than always implying a hardware bug.

<sup>1</sup> Evidently, the `lock`-prefixed instruction *also* perform an atomic operation which isn't possible to achieve solely with `mfence`, so the `lock`-prefixed instructions definitely have additional functionality. Therefore, for `mfence` to be useful, we would expect it either to have additional barrier semantics in some scenarios, *or* to perform better.

<sup>2</sup> It is also entirely possible that he was reading a different version of the manual where the prose was different.

<sup>3</sup> `SFENCE` in SSE, `lfence` and `mfence` in SSE2.

<sup>4</sup> And often it's slower: Agner has it listed at 33 cycles latency on recent hardware, while locked instructions are usually about 20 cycles.

Comment: On Skylake, `xchg [shared], eax` is a barrier for NT stores.  Tested with this code that fills a buffer and stores current output position every cache line to a shared variable with (`mfence`+)`mov` or `xchg`: https://godbolt.org/g/7Q9xgz (some timing results in comments, from ocperf.py on the whole thing, so the timing includes the time for `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)`).  With just `mov` but not `mfence`, we get reordering.  But `mfence`+`mov` is ok, and so is `xchg`.  The speed of the consumer loop is much different for the two producers, so there's some major difference.

Comment: That doesn't rule out `lock`ed instructions not fencing `movntdqa` loads from WC memory; I think I've seen a claim that `mfence` (not just `lfence`) is necessary there.  The difference when interacting with a consumer thread that spins on reading is interesting and bears further investigation (perhaps with something that profiles producer and consumer separately, and doesn't count the time to `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)` ~4GiB of RAM.  Also, testing on AMD CPUs would be interesting; the x86 docs on paper seem ambiguous, so the fact that `xchg` is a barrier on Intel doesn't tell us what they mean.

Comment: BTW, I compiled with `t=nt-produce+consume.xchg; g++ -Wall -std=gnu++17 -march=native -pthread -O2 nt-fence-lock-buffer.cpp -o $t && taskset -c 3,4 ocperf.py stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,machine_clears.memory_ordering -r3 ./"$t"` (using gcc7.3.0 on Arch Linux on i7-6700k with DDR4-2666, with the CPU governor running it at ~3.8GHz for most of the test).

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, I had it on my to-do list for a while to run your tests, but now that this errata information has come to light, I think we can say that is highly likely that `lock`ed instructions are intended to, and do actually fence NT stores in the usual way, since we have the NT load errata and NT stores to WB-memory are an order of magnitude or two more common and spread across all kinds of code, so a divergence there would likely have been noted (and the fact that the load behavior deserved an errata means we can understand that Intel likely intended `lock` to fence).

Comment: In case of regular loads and stores. An MFENCE provides all 4 barriers `[LoadLoad][LoadStore][StoreLoad][StoreStore]`, An Atomic operation provides `r1=Y,[LoadLoad][LoadStore]..[StoreStore][LoadStore]Y=r1[StoreLoad]`. So from a barrier perspective MFENCE and an atomic operation are equal. Is my understanding correct. (X86 provides LoadLoad/LoadStore/StoreStore).

Comment: @pveentjer - from a barrier perspective *on WB memory* that is correct (although the 4 barriers are not a complete way to think about x86-TSO since they don't explain store forwarding). The difference with `mfence` and locked instructions seems only to arise with WC memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes , If I write something to memory such as updating a struct and then doing an interlocked operation to atomically update a pointer to this struct, will other threads that also use interlocked operation to read that pointer see the new values I wrote to memory? Or do I need to do a mfence before interlocked operation to make sure the store buffer was flushed and values are updated globally?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, atomic RMWs on x86 are as strong as C++11 `memory_order_seq_cst`, so they include both acquire and release.  You only need a plain `mov` store and a plain `mov` load on x86 to get the amount of synchronization you need to publish a pointer to other threads and have them see the pointed-to data.  (C++ `...release` and `...acquire`).  But if you need atomic RMWs in the writers and readers for some other reason, that's automatically sufficient.  And already covered by this answer.